# Copy and rename at the same time

Tags: command-line, copy, rename

I need to copy `sample.txt` from `foo/` to `bar/` and when pasting in `bar/` that should be renamed as `test.txt`

What is the command i need to use for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can paste it under different name.

```
$ ls foo/
sample.txt
$ cp foo/sample.txt bar/test.txt
$ ls bar/
test.txt
$
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :)

Comment: @CodeFrc Please do accept the answer if you think it's useful, thanks.